# A school book uses the relation \$ \eta=\frac{V_{s}I_{s}}{V_{p}I_{p}}×100\$% to calculate the efficiency of a transformer. Is that correct?

Tags: transformer

The school book uses \$ \eta=\frac{V_{s}I_{s}}{V_{p}I_{p}}×100\$% to calculate the efficiency of non-ideal transformer.

It also uses the relation \$ \frac{I_{s}}{I_{p}}=\frac{N_{p}}{N_{s}}\$ for non ideal transformers.

I think it was fine until it used \$ 
 \frac{I_{s}}{I_{p}}  =\frac{N_{p}}{N_{s}}\$ to substantiate for \$ \frac{I_{s}}{I_{p}} \$ in \$ \eta=\frac{V_{s}I_{s}}{V_{p}I_{p}}×100\$%, because \$ \frac{I_{s}}{I_{p}}  =\frac{N_{p}}{N_{s}}\$ is only true for ideal transformers.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *what do you think?*

Correct, the magnetization current is part of \$I_P\$ hence, multiplying \$V_P\$ by \$I_P\$ is technically wrong. It's also wrong on another count in that the phase relationship between \$V_P\$ and \$I_P\$ has to be taken into account and, when you do, the two RMS values should never be blindly multiplied.

In many circumstances it's good enough of course.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking it is IsVs*/IpVp* where the quantities are phasors, with a possible minus sign depending on reference directions. This accounts for the phase as mentioned above.

Beyond that relating efficiency to transformer parameters depends on the transformer model.